# Swift cache base64 string UIImage data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caching

I'm trying to cache UIImage that images come from service(I'm using Alamofire). Service sends me a base64 string and I'm converting base64 to data then print in tableviewcell with

```
cell.imageview.image = UIImage(data: imageDatas[indexPath.row])
```

I searched lots of libraries like Kingfisher , AlamofireImage but they are caching URL image can't find anyway to cache image with base64 string.So I find a similar example and try this :

```
  private let cache = NSCache<NSNumber, UIImage>()
  private let utilityQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)

   private func loadImage(data : Data , completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
       utilityQueue.async {
           
        
           let image = imageDataDecodingClass.imageDataDecoding(imageData: data)
           
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               completion(image)
           }
       }
   }
```

in cell :

```
       let itemNumber = indexPath.section * 2 + 1
       let imageData =  (showcaseDatas[indexPath.section * 2 + 1].Document?.Document!)!
       if let cachedImage = self.cache.object(forKey: NSNumber(value: itemNumber)) {
           cell.showcaseImage.image = cachedImage
      } else {
          cell.addSubview(progressHUDimage)
          self.loadImage(data: imageData, completion: {ret in
              cell.showcaseImage.image = ret
              self.cache.setObject(cell.showcaseImage.image!, forKey: NSNumber(value: itemNumber))
              progressHUDimage.removeFromSuperview()
          })
    }
```

Its caching image perfectly but when I scroll tableview ,CPU increased a lot (%70-90) thats why tableview is not smoothing.

So , my question is , How can I cache base64 string image in tableviewcell with smoothing and without CPU increased ? Thanks

Comment: Excually I'm caching Data but problem still exist @Larme

Comment: If you don't want to do it yourself, try AlamofireImage

Answer (score 2):

If you are caching base64 `String` or `Data` there will be always a hit in decoding them as an image. The only way it would be caching the `UIImage` itself, but this will come with trade off of memory depending on the size of your images.
I can only give you few advices:

- Use NSCache (it seems that you are already using it)
- Resize your images on another thread to have a perfect fit on the size that  you are rendering on screen and cache them only after they have been resized
- Be sure that the performance hit you are seeing is not due to other reasons
- Cache images by using their index path if you are using for cells
- Create your `NSCache` with a memory limit and a number of element limit

You can also try to create 2 caches, one for ready to go already decode images and the other one as a fallback with `Data` object.
The fact that your `Data` objects are small it doesn't means that also images are, it really depends on the compression that has been used to save the image representation.
There are also more advance technique using memory mapping on physical memory.